# Setting the sonar file, sonar.properties, no useful after restarting the service

Tags: sonarqube

sonar bulild sucess
but analysis error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`
set sonar.properties but not use

```
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx6144m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx6144m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryErro
sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xms512m -Xmx6144m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

check ui setting  is not use

Answer (score 1):

Increase the memory via the SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS environment variable:

```
export SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="-Xmx512m"
```

On Windows environments, avoid the double-quotes, since they get misinterpreted and combine the two parameters into a single one.

```
set SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 0):

is unuseful ，mypoject is scan (by maven) sucess but SonarQube background task fails with an out-of-memory error.

`https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARqube71/Java+Process+Memory`

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in official documentation,

You need to define `SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS` as environment variable with desired heap space.

[Documentation link here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/)